# Copy An Excel table in a worksheet with styling to an msg file using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, outlook, pywin32

I have an Excel worksheet with a table that I want to copy into an msg file with the styling.

I know how to do the msg part:

```
import win32com.client as win32

def read_excel_into_msg(excel_file,msg_file):

    excel_table = ''

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(msg_file)
    msg.HTMLBody = excel_table
    msg.SaveAs(msg_file)
```

How can I get the excel table from a worksheet in the excel file to attach it to the msg body?

- I have tried:

```
excel_table = pandas.read_excel(excel_file,sheetname,header=n,usecols=cols)
excel_table = excel_table.to_html()
```

But it copied the plain table without the styling (the header and footer colors)

Comment: Are you adding as image to the email body?

Comment: @0m3r I need to add it as a table!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Pillow Library](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) Imaging Library, copy range, save it then add it to Outlook `html body`

Example, I'm using pywin32

```
import os
import win32com.client
from PIL import ImageGrab


workbook_path = r"D:\Temp\test.xlsx"

excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=workbook_path)
sheet = workbook.Sheets["sheet1"]
copy_range = sheet.Range("A1:C6").CopyPicture(Appearance=1, Format=2)

ImageGrab.grabclipboard().save("copy_range.png")
image_path = os.getcwd() + "\\copy_range.png"

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = '0m3r@Email.com'
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
html_body = """<div><img src={}></img></div>"""
mail.HTMLBody = html_body.format(image_path)

mail.Display()
```

if not image then use [Inspector.WordEditor property (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Inspector.WordEditor), make sure Word is the default email editor

Example

```
import win32com.client

workbook_path = r"D:\Temp\test.xlsx"

excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=workbook_path)
sheet = workbook.Sheets["sheet1"]
excel_table = sheet.Range("Table1[#All]").Copy()

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Display()

inspector = mail.GetInspector.WordEditor
inspector.Range(Start=0, End=0).Paste()
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great! But is there anyway I can add the table instead of a screenshot of the table?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. says operation failed at the GetInspector.WordEditor line

Comment: @joon is ms Word the default email editor?

Comment: Yes, word is the default email editor!